# No podspec found for `Flutter` in `.symlinks/flutter/ios` running on Travis CI

Tags: flutter, travis-ci

When trying to run `pod install` to build Flutter iOS app on Travis CI, I face the following error:

`No podspec found for 'Flutter' in '.symlinks/flutter/ios'`

It seems to be a problem with Travis env, because it works normally on my local machine.

.travis.yml:

```
language: objective-c
os: osx
osx_image: xcode11.3
xcode_workspace: $TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR/flutter/my-project/ios/Runner.xcworkspace
podfile: $TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR/flutter/my-project/ios/Podfile

install:
  # Install Flutter
  - cd ..
  - git clone https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
  - export PATH="$PATH:`pwd`/flutter/bin"

  # Run Flutter Doctor
  - flutter doctor -v

  - cd $TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR/flutter/my-project
  - flutter pub get
  - cd ios
  - bundle install
  - pod install


script:
...
```

Comment: Having the same issue.  Did you ever find a resolution?

Comment: Sorry, couldn't find a solution to this :/